# Want to choose something between count(*) or count(distinct *)

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table
with

### Column1

```
        A 
        A
        A
        B
        B
        C
        C
        C
```

---

### Column2

```
        CH 
        FH
        FH 
        BW
        CH
        AW
```

---

Now: I want to have a select sth---> result 6 different combinations of column1 and column 2.
If i say select count(column2): I'll take 8.I don't want it.
If i say select(distinct column2): I'll take 5.I don't want it either.

The 6 different results I look for are: A-QW,A-CH,B-FH,C-BW,C-CH,C-AW 
I'm looking for combinations.
Can you helpt me?

Comment: I love that some people seem to know what you're talking about. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping will do what you need. It will conveniently eliminate the duplicates for you.

```
select column1, column2
  from <your_table>
  group by column1, column2
```

Pretty sure this will do what you want.  [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31a40/1)

**update based on comment**

```
select count(*) from (
    select column1, column2
      from <your_table>
      group by column1, column2
) q
```

[updated demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31a40/11)

Comment: Nice,but if i want to have as an answer just the number 6 and not the rows?

Comment: Nice,but if i want to have as an answer just the number 6 and not the rows?This command will return 6 rows,but will not answer to me with the number 6.

Comment: @JAMAICA glad it worked - if you're happy with the answer, can you please mark it as accepted by clicking on the 'tick' under the votes? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM  tblname GROUP BY Column1,Column2
```

Comment: interesting that the second answer, which is an exact duplicate of the first answer, gets upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, we can use an expression which combines the two columns...

As an example:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(t.column1,'-',t.column2)) AS cnt_combinations
  FROM mytable t
```

This only works in the special case, where we know that a dash character isn't included as a character in `column1` or `column2`. Adding that delimiter character isn't strictly necessary either.

In the more general case, this wouldn't produce the "correct" results if the contents of the columns included values like.

```
column1  column2  CONCAT(column1,'-',column2)
-------  -------  ---------------------------
A        -CW      A--CW
A-       CW       A--CW
```

Since the result of the expression is the same value, those won't be seen as distinct values.

The same thing happens with `NULL` values, because `CONCAT()` will return `NULL` whenever any of the argument values is `NULL`.

For example, using the string `NULL` to represent a NULL value

```
column1  column2  CONCAT(column1,'-',column2)
-------  -------  ---------------------------
NULL     CW       NULL
A        NULL     NULL
```